# Activity has leaked window at Dialog show() method

Tags: java, android

This happens when I upload three large size images through an API call by `volley`.

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.laeb.laebproject.CreateTeamActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{390f2144 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,232} that was originally added here
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:457)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:311)
                                                                         at com.laeb.laebproject.team_fragments.FragmentCreateTeam.createTeam(FragmentCreateTeam.java:151)
                                                                         at com.laeb.laebproject.team_fragments.FragmentCreateTeam$1.onClick(FragmentCreateTeam.java:120)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: I think you are missing dialog.dismiss() method.

Comment: no i am not missing the dialog dimes method

Comment: there should be another error in logcat before this one that is the actual problem. This error is side effect of it. Could you please scroll up & check before this error?